# How to call a model method inside MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have an instance variable in my Rails method like this(which I will later use)

```
def index
    @users = User.select("users.id as usr_id,
                          users.name as user_name,
                          users.first_price as price,
                          users.tax as tax,
 (#here's model method)=> users.sum_all as grand_total")
                        .where("users.deleted_at is null AND
                         users.id IN (?)
                         @users.pluck(:id))
                        .order(@order_by)
end
```

And I want to implement a model method in this query which looks like this

```
User < ApplicationRecord
  def sum_all
    self.first_price + self.tax
  end
end
```

If I put this method as above I'm getting an error

```
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"#\u003cActionView::Template::Error: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.sum_all' in 'field list'}
```

Comment: You should not do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should avoid doing that. Instead, you can make the above query work by adding the two field values in the query itself.

```
def index
    @users = User.select("users.id as usr_id,
                          users.name as user_name,
                          users.first_price as price,
                          users.tax as tax,
                          users.first_price + users.tax as grand_total")
                 .where("users.deleted_at is null AND users.id IN (?)", @users.pluck(:id))
                 .order(@order_by)
end
```